# How to handle this thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

In My application there is one thread running in activity A while it is call. Now i am going to another activity B with doing nothing to that thread. 
There are also another thread on activity B.
Now after finishing on activity on activity B. I come back to the activity A.

At that time i got error that the thread on activity A is already running.
So, what should i have to do to handle this error ???
Every time my application get crashed while i come back from activity B to A.

Thanks.

In this Error log Drawing surface is my Activity A as said above.
Error Log:

```
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1322)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.example.drawing.DrawingSurface.surfaceCreated(DrawingSurface.java:113)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:532)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:206)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:3891)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:719)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:719)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:719)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:719)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:744)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-10 15:08:24.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

DrawingSurface class where i got Error:

```
public class DrawingSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private Boolean _run;
protected DrawThread thread;
public Canvas canvas = null;
private CommandManager commandManager;
//private Bitmap myBitmap;
private Bitmap mBitmap;

public DrawingSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    commandManager = new CommandManager();
    thread = new DrawThread(getHolder());
}

class DrawThread extends Thread{
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder){
        mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;

    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Canvas canvas = null;
        while (_run){

            try{
                canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                if(mBitmap == null){
                    mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                }

                final Canvas c = new Canvas (mBitmap);
                //canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                c.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE); 
//             Bitmap kangoo =   BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);

                if(!(DrawingActivity.imagePath==null)){
                    c.drawBitmap(DrawingActivity.mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
                }
                commandManager.executeAll(c);
                canvas.drawBitmap (mBitmap, 0,  0,null);
            } finally {

                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }

    }
}


public void addDrawingPath (DrawingPath drawingPath){
    commandManager.addCommand(drawingPath);
}

public boolean hasMoreRedo(){
    return commandManager.hasMoreRedo();
}

public void redo(){
    commandManager.redo();
}

public void undo(){
    commandManager.undo();
}

public boolean hasMoreUndo(){
    return commandManager.hasMoreRedo();
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(){
    return mBitmap;
}


public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,  int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);;
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start(); // error at this line
        if(!thread.isAlive())            
             thread.start();  
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean retry = true;
    thread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // we will try it again and again...
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Post some code and also error log.

Comment: In which of your Activities methods do you start the thread Running?

Comment: Please post code for thread, how you are implementing the thread.

Comment: In My Application I am running thread to paint and draw on the canvas. from there if i call another activity and then come back, at that time i got error. I am just going to upload the error log.

Comment: Just read the Error log and tell me. I will put that code.

Comment: If possible just finish or stop that thread before going to another activity.

Comment: do you start your thread in the onResume callback?

Comment: @user370305  : ok But will it works if i am comming back to that activity ? And what code i have to use to finish the thread ? I mean if the object is thread then should i have to use thread.stop() or thread.finish(); ??

Comment: no, use a while loop with flag and inside it just start a thread whenever you done your work make that flag false so your thread automatic finish.

Comment: @all: Please see my updated question. I have put the call DrawingSurface where i got the error. I have commented the line where i got error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Thread` and `Runnable`, if you go with `AsyncTask`, they will close themselves automatically after you navigate away from an activity.

or if you want to use `Thread` only, you'll have to use `t.interrupt()` to stop any running `Thread` `t` before moving away from the activity.

so, I guess put `t.interrupt()` in `onPause()` method of the activity to stop the `Thread`

Edit: this line is redundunt

```
if(!thread.isAlive())            
             thread.start();
```

and i dont understand what you are trying to do with this,

```
thread.setRunning(true);
```

this might be creating some problems remove this and try again

i.e. try this

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        thread.start(); // error at this line 
}
```

Comment: hmmm.. let me take a closer look

Comment: i have edited my answer try it with thread.interrupt() in onPause() of activity in which this view is contained, check if it solves the issue

Comment: OK. Let me check it. And if you update the answer then let me know.

Comment: you might be right but i am Drawing on canvas using that code. Thats why i am using it. Now How to solve that problem? If i comment that it is not going to work.

Comment: I am stumped, try this, finish your activities when user navigates off, start activities with FLAG_CLEAR_TOP, see if it works, I would suggest you start a bounty on this

Comment: How to do that ? Start Activity with FLAG_CLEAR_TOP ?

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(this, UI.class) .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

Comment: Ok Thanks for help and Support.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work (most of the time -> race condition):

```
   thread.start(); // error at this line
   if(!thread.isAlive()) thread.start();
```

Don't do that. A thread may only be started **once** and there is definitely **no** reason to re-try starting it.

`thread.start();` is really all you will ever need to start a thread.

EDIT:

```
while (retry) {
  thread.join();
  retry = false;
}
```

does not make any sense. Just `join()` and possibly relay the interruption to your `thread`.

Comment: ok. But even if i comment that two line, I got the same error. Now what should i do ?

Comment: As I said: You **cannot** start a thread more than *once*. However, in your code, you only create **one** thread object in your constructor which may be asked to *start()* multiple times, i.e. each time *surfaceCreated()* is executed. You probably need to create a new thread in *surfaceCreated()*.

Comment: What's the error now? - Show us your edited code and the new logcat.

Comment: Same error is there. And if i caome back, the application is not anle to draw on canvas.